# Rank Correlation between ordinal and continuous variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation, rank

I have to do a rank correlation in Matlab. I have a matrix with the variables: trial, Lvl, Rating.
Lvl is an ordinal variable with 6 levels. Rating is a continuous variable.

[image: This is my matrix]

I need to calculate the rank correlation between these two variables in Matlab.
I was thinking of something like this:

```
rho = corr(myTable.Lvl, myTable.rating, 'type', 'Spearman');
```

Is this correct? Also, my doubt is that the var "rating" is continuous. Can I run the rank correlation between an ordinal and a continuous variable?

Thank you all for your time.

Gluce